# Why the kernel wasn't updated to 4.4 on Ubuntu 14.04? Other related questions

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, kernel, update

I had a task to update *only* kernel to the latest version on `Ubuntu 14.04` VPS.

What I did:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-virtual
reboot
```

It updated from `3.13.0-24` to `3.13.0-163`.

14.04.x Ubuntu Kernel Support Schedule: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support and `apt-cache search linux-generic` tells me that, `linux-image-4.4.0-98` exists.

### Questions:

1. Why the kernel wasn't updated to the latest `4.4.0-98` or newer version? I got `3.13.0-163` instead.
2. Is there any difference between `4.4` and `3.13` as they are both currently supported?
3. In order to update kernel to `4.4` do I need to update ubuntu to `14.04.5`?
4. How to update to `4.4` without updating the whole system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:

```
apt install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

This will update kernel to `4.4`.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to take on a task to upgrade this system to a newer LTS, as [Ubuntu 14.04 is end of life in a few months](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Or acquire security updates some other way such as [Ubuntu ESM](https://www.ubuntu.com/esm).

---

Read that schedule graph carefully. The released major kernel version is locked in but continues to get supported, for security fixes.

[Their kernel release policy](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) adds the next 4 Ubuntu release kernels, for hardware and feature enablement. These are different kernel package names, reflecting a quite different kernel. Do a [search for linux in the release](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-generic&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) and look for the major version you want.